# Button below android listview

Tags: android, listview

So I tried all the other post and it's not working, can anyone tell me why the button gets pu into the listview?

The code for my layout is:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="#5eff6c"
tools:context=".FriendActivity">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:background="#5eff6c" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textIsSelectable="false" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Now it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU1Fb.png

I want this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7b6j.png

Edit: 
Java code:

```
public class FriendActivity extends ListActivity {

private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> names = null;
        try {
            String test = new sendData().execute().get();
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(test);
            Log.d("NOOO", String.valueOf(test));

            names = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            JSONObject object;
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                object = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.d("YES", String.valueOf(object));

                String name = object.getString(TAG_NAME);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                names.add(map);
        }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, names,
            R.layout.activity_friend,
            new String[]{TAG_NAME}, new int[]{
            R.id.name});

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

        }
    });
}

}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you post the java code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing that layout to each of your `ListView`'s layout here:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, names,
            R.layout.activity_friend,
            new String[]{TAG_NAME}, new int[]{
            R.id.name});
```

And what you want to do is to set that layout this way:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_friend);
```

That way, it will be set to the activity and your activity will look like what you made in your xml.

Also make another simple layout with a single `TextView` in it and pass that to your adapter, this way your `ListView` will have also a text in it. Or you could use this layout from android: `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` .

Also for the button gravity I think you should use:

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
```

And don't forget to remove the textview from the layout you posted above as you won't need it anymore..

Comment: Where do I put the "setContentView(R.layout.activity_friend);" ?

Comment: In onCreate, right after: super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: Ok, but how do i make the SimpleAdapter not use the Layout for every listview item?

Comment: As I said above, just replace the R.layout.activity_friend with android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 in the adapter.. :)